# ion-img doesn't work inside an ion-card - Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I think I’m facing a strange issue. I’m trying to show an image using `ion-img` inside an `ion-card` component :

```
<ion-card>
    <ion-img src="https://www.mywebsite.com/images/stories/koloheandino24.jpg" ></ion-img>
</ion-card>
```

But it doesn't work!!

The exact same code with any HTML tag before `ion-img`, it works!!!

```
<ion-card>
    <span>bla bla ...</span>
    <ion-img src="https://www.mywebsite.com/images/stories/koloheandino24.jpg" ></ion-img>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: you can check your CSS , might be issue there

Comment: I have the same issue, when I add a tag before ion-img it strangely works

Comment: why add image directly in ion-card, put the ion-img inside ion-card-content and everything should be the same and work normally

Answer (score 0):

This work. Check again your image link.

```
<ion-card>
    <ion-img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564446586861-7469f94e9c98?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" ></ion-img>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution : Add `min-height: 1px` to `ion-img`**

There is an open issue in github, and in [this comment](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/18734#issuecomment-509669151) the author found this solution.

I quote the author :

> Putting this here for others who might run across this problem. Setting a min-height on the ion-img element seems to resolve the issue:
>
> in your global.scss (or other relevant stylesheet):

```
:root {
  ion-img {
    /** 
     * Bug fix for:
     * https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/18734
     */
    min-height: 1px !important;
  }
}
```